# Eclipse plug-in development Unable to instantiate class due to java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:

Tags: eclipse, plugins

Title: Eclipse plug-in development Unable to instantiate class due to  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:

Trying to build an eclipse plugin but getting some runtime error..

I understand this is due to a class file that the code depends on and it is present at compile time but not found at runtime....

I'm not sure what I have to do to fix this.
the source file of the file that is not found is in my project workspace.

the project containing of the source file is in the JavaBuildPath of the troubled project as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll need to put the project of the missing file as dependency in the plugin configuration file too. Then it'll be available at runtime.

Comment: A simple change is often the only thing needed ;)

Comment: Alan, how did you do that?