# Eclipse TFS - Source Control Explorer Error

Tags: eclipse, tfs, eclipse-plugin

I am using Eclipse (version Juno) with the TFS Plugin. When I click Source Code Explorer I get this error message:

> Plug-in "com.microsoft.tfs.client.common.ui.vcexplorer" was unable to
>   instantiate class
>   "com.microsoft.tfs.client.common.ui.vcexplorer.versioncontrol.VersionControlEditor".

[image]

I saw this [Eclipse plug-in development Unable to instantiate class due to java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/468316/eclipse-plug-in-development-unable-to-instantiate-class-due-to-java-lang-noclass) but am not sure if it is the fix for this TFS plugin or what it really means:

> put the project of the missing file as dependency in the plugin
>   configuration file too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've seen this exact error before on my box. In my case this file had gone missing due to its long path and filename:

> "...plugins\com.microsoft.tfs.client.common.ui.vcexplorer_10.1.0.201101271439\com\microsoft\tfs\client\common\ui\vcexplorer\versioncontrol\ VersionControlEditor$VersionControlEditorRepositoryUpdatedListener.class"

You can see how this can get somewhat long. I'd suggest checking if you have all the files perhaps comparing it with an installation on a shorter path. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a go tomorrow and report back, +1 I hope it works! - I have got a perfect install being copied across right now for the comparison tomorrow morning:) And that copy is installed on a shorter path...

Comment: The copy works from temp. I dont have time to troubleshoot. I'll mark your answer as correct for now, but if I get a chance or anyone else poses a better solution I'll investigate further.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this can help somebody that researches this error. I was able to fix the problem on a virtual machine (Windows Server 2012 R2) running on a Windows 7 desktop with Eclipse Mars 4.5.0 and TFS plugin 14.0.1.

> Plug-in "com.microsoft.tfs.client.common.ui.vcexplorer" was unable to
>   instantiate class
>   "com.microsoft.tfs.client.common.ui.vcexplorer.versioncontrol.VersionControlEditor".

I installed Eclipse and the TFS plug-in on both the desktop Win 7 and the virtual machine. It worked perfect on Win 7 but on the virtual machine running Windows Server the error came up.

My first step to solve this was by following *moerketh* advice and moved that specific file from Win 7 to Server 2012.

> ...plugins\com.microsoft.tfs.client.common.ui.vcexplorer_10.1.0.201101271439\com\microsoft\tfs\client\common\ui\vcexplorer\versioncontrol\
>   VersionControlEditor$VersionControlEditorRepositoryUpdatedListener.class

It did remove the error but did not show the folders in the server. In other words, I couldn't see the folders I am trying to map to.

Next, I decided to copy all files in the folder as shown below and paste it to the same folder in the virtual machine.

> ...plugins\com.microsoft.tfs.client.common.ui.vcexplorer_10.1.0.201101271439\com\microsoft\tfs\client\common\ui\vcexplorer\versioncontrol\
>   VersionControlEditor$VersionControlEditorRepositoryUpdatedListener.class

Restarted Eclipse, and then the TFS folders showed.